# activeadmin: adding delete for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a infrastructure object composed for many datacenters. In the apps/admin/infrastructures.rb I have the following code:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Infrastructure details" do
    f.input :name

    f.has_many :datacenters do |datacenter_form|
      datacenter_form.input :name        
    end
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

I can add datacenters with no problems but I don't know how I can delete it from infrastructure form.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Sep 2017 Update:

**Rails 5.1.4, ActiveAdmin 1.0.0**

Append `:id` and `_destroy` in `permit_params` along with other attributes from the model e.g. `:name` in your case. Then provide the `:allow_destroy` option in `f.has_many` too. Other requirements remain the same; like adding `allow_destroy: true` in `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Final look:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Infrastructure do
  permit_params :name, datacenters_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :name]

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Infrastructure details" do
      f.input :name

      f.has_many :datacenters, heading: false,
                               allow_destroy: true,
                               new_record: false do |datacenter_form|
        datacenter_form.input :name        
      end
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

[ActiveAdmin Reference](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#nested-resources)

---

This worked for me:

```
     i.input :_destroy, as: :boolean
```

and in the Model remember to add :allow_destroy :

```
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
```

Comment: With Rails 4, it only worked for me once I permitted `:_destroy` through my strong parameters: `permit_params ..., nested_model_attributes: [:_destroy, ... ]`

Comment: I'd forgotten the `allow_destroy: true` option on `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: I thought permit_params was enough, thank you! none of the other answers mention this.

Answer (score 14):

Solved adding the following line:

```
datacenter_form.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove'
```

The code looks like:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Infrastructure details" do
    f.input :name

    f.has_many :datacenters do |datacenter_form|
      datacenter_form.input :name
      datacenter_form.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove'
    end
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Comment: this works, but it just seems sloppy. Is there a way to add the Delete button that active admin has when you add a new nested resource to existing resources on an update?

Comment: Agreed. Why doesn't the delete button appear for persisted records?

Comment: Agreed is there anyway to get a button?

Comment: Yes, has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

If you cant destroy the object nested. You need to put :_destroy in your  app/admin/object.rb permit_params

```
permit_params :id,:name, :cod, :_destroy
```

Comment: In case of nested attributes needed to be destroyed, the `:_destroy` param should be in the `nested_attributes` attributes. => ( permit_params :attr, :attr, <nestedattr>_attributes: [:attr, :attr, :_destroy]

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will be helpful (I've changed my code to suit your example, so I hope there are no typos here):

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Infrastructure details" do
      f.input :name

      f.has_many :datacenters do |datacenter_form|
        datacenter_form.inputs :datacenters do
          datacenter_form.input :name
        end
        datacenter_form.buttons do
          link_to "Delete", admin_datacenter_path(datacenter_form.object), method: "delete", class: "button" unless datacenter_form.object.new_record?
        end
      end
    end
    f.buttons
  end
```

and the controller method should be defined in datacenters.rb

```
controller do
    def destroy
      @datacenter = Datacenter.find(params[:id])
      @datacenter.destroy
      redirect_to edit_admin_retailer_path(@datacenter.infrastructure)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
datacenter_form.label :_delete
datacenter_form.check_box :_delete
```

This adds a checkbox for each nested object which will delete the object if checked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting this error: "undefined method `_delete' for #<Datacenter:0x000000051d3170>"

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the following to your parent model

```
has_many :child_name, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your answer. Provide an explanation of what this does and how the code snippet answers the question.